# Toggle between selected dropdown values on each code run in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What I want to do is I want to toggle between two values of the dropdown. Each time I run the code, I should see the dropdown value changed to the other one. For having a go at it, please access the URL 'https://ant.design/components/select/' and help me to toggle between the values 'Jack' and 'Lucy' which you can see in Examples given. What I tried is as follows.

```
WebElement orgadminselected=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ant-select-selection-selected-value' and text()='Lucy']"));
        WebElement userselected=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ant-select-selection-selected-value' and text()='Jack']"));
        try {
        System.out.println(orgadminselected.getText());}catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        try {System.out.println(userselected.getText());}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        WebElement orgadmindropdown=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ant-select-selection-selected-value' and text()='Lucy']"));
        WebElement userdropdown=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ant-select-selection-selected-value' and text()='Jack']"));
        if(orgadminselected.isSelected()) {
            userdropdown.click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ant-select-selection__placeholder' and text()='Select Organization']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='ant-select-dropdown-menu-item' and text()='TDL Care A5']")).click();
        }
        else if(userselected.isSelected()){
            orgadmindropdown.click();
        }
```

But it is giving me error 'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //div[@class='ant-select-selection-selected-value' and text()='Jack']'. Please help.